# How to disable a ToolStripButton?

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, mdiparent

How to disable or hide `ToolStripButton` from MDIparent after a user login?

For example, in a login form: 
If the user enters a username that is not admin, a certain `ToolStripButton` will be disabled or hidden.

The entry point of my application is the MDIparent. 
Within my MDIparent the login form loads by calling the `ShowDialog` method.

Comment: `toolstripbutton.Enabled = false;` maybe?

Comment: MDIparent1.toolStripButtonBorrow.Enabled = false; don't work

Comment: try making a function in your MDIparent1 where you will enable/disable all your toolstripbuttons. Then once you click Login button on your Login Form, call that function.

Answer (score 6):

To disable or hide you can use *Enabled* or *Available* properies

```
  // Make button gray (disable)
  myStripButton.Enabled = false;

  // Make button invisible (hide)
  myStripButton.Available = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for this hint! I was using `.Visible = false` to hide it, but that did not work. `.Avalilable = false` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnTrasactions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnTrasactions.Enabled = false;
    Trasaction trans = new Trasaction();
    trans.MdiParent = this;
    trans.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(trans_Closed);
    trans.Show();
 }

 private void trans_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
 {
     btnTrasactions.Enabled = true;
 }
```

Comment: Hello try above whole code It will definitely help you...I used here in MDI form Toolstrip and button and on that button click I disable that button as well as create one dynamic Event as " trans_Closed " . In this method i enabled the button which is took in Toolstrip. so it will Work fine